# recursively delete every nodes in binary tree

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

Following is my code to recursively delete every nodes in a Binary Search Tree:

```
template <class T>
bool BST<T>::clear()
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Empty" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        clearNodes(root);
        return true;
    }

}

template <class T>
void BST<T>::clearNodes(BTNode<T> *cur)
{
    if(cur == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    clearNodes(cur->left);
    clearNodes(cur->right);

    delete cur;
}
```

In my main function, when I try to print out the content to check whether the nodes are deleted after running my clear function, somehow I encounter the weird display here:
[image]

May I know that is my nodes are actually deleted through the clear function above?

Thanks for your guides!

Comment: `delete` does not change your tree structure.  All you did was deallocate the memory, leaving your tree with invalid nodes.   Also, `delete` does not set pointers to NULL, which it seems your code is relying on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume "checking that the nodes are deleted" is equivalent to `clear()` printing empty. Your algorithm is missing the step where it reset the deleted node.

A modified version is

```
template <class T>
void BST<T>::clearNodes(BTNode<T>* &cur) //reference on pointer
{
  if (cur==NULL)
  {
    return;
  }

  clearNodes(cur->left);
  clearNodes(cur->right);

delete cur;
cur = NULL; //neccessary
}
```

**Edit : Explanation about changes**
Once you observe the issue about the node not set to null, the first iteration will be to set the node in question after every call, ie

```
clearNodes(cur->right);
cur->right = NULL;
```

This give the responsibility to the caller, and his a potential defect because sooner or later the caller may forget to set to null or may set the wrong value. Thus you want to set in `clearNodes`.In order to modify a pointer inside the function you need to pass either a pointer to it or a reference. In c++, I prefer to pass a reference. Thus the signature become¨

```
void BST<T>::clearNodes(BTNode<T>* &cur);
```

Comment: Hi, UmNyobe, thanks for your guides and I did it. Things are working fine after following your edits. By the way, I'm curious why the 2 changes are necessary? I feel that understanding the algorithm is important to me rather than getting the answer solely. I appreciate your effort if you could get me some further ideas. Thank you =)

Comment: Hi UmNyobe. I wanted to make sure `cur` has NULL children and wrote `if (nullptr == cur->left && nullptr == cur->right) { delete cur; cur = nullptr; }` in the latter part, but then valgrind reports there's a memory leak. Apparently that `if` condition is the culprit. Can you please explain why this is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the root of the tree is not set to Null, therefor it holds garbage, and the print function is iterating a random-garbage tree.
Make sure you set NULL to the tree root when the clear method ends.

```
template <class T>
bool BST<T>::clear()
{ 
   if (root==NULL)
  {
    cout << "Empty" << endl;
    return false;
  }

  else
  {
    clearNodes(root);
    root = NULL;
    return true;
  }     

}
```

I assume that when you print - you check if the tree root is null or not in order to determine whether the tree is empty or not.